# PK and FK finding algorithm

Tags: sql-server, database, algorithm, primary-key

How can an algorithm is written to find Primary Keys and Foreign Keys of a relation ?
Given parameters are name of relation, degree of relation and an array of the attributes(a primary key may include more than one attribute)

I think if an attribute is referenced than it is primary key. and the attirbute that references is FK

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would urge you to read this question and ask yourself if you would have any idea what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Ok, let's start first by what did you try?

Comment: I think if an attribute is referenced than it is primary key. and the attirbute that references is FK

Comment: That adds nothing to the clarity here. I suspect this isn't all that difficult to answer but we don't know what the question is. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming the data you would run this algorithm against would be a loose collection of tables, perhaps imported into database form, but for which nothing has been marked as a primary or foreign key, either in the source files or the resulting database?

Comment: @Lori these tables references each other with proper pk and fk but imagine we dont know which attribıtes are pk or fk..(it is an algorithmic question, not based on a real problem)

Comment: If the tables are defined with pk and fk then you do know which columns are involved. You look at sys.indexes and sys.foreign_keys and sys.foreign_key_columns. Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: I dont have physical model I just have conceptual model.

Comment: Is this a home work

Comment: Question is clear and the answer is below. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is not clear. Are you talking about getting metadata about what DBMS constraints have been declared, or are you talking about determining what constraints should be declared? If the former, this is an easily found duplicate. If the the latter, start reading a textbook & ask a question the first place you are stuck. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: Somebody guessing doesn't make your question clear. Also that post is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a list of columns that contain no redundancies and no null cells as possible primary keys. I suppose one fast way to detect them would be to attempt to declare the column as a PK and see if there are errors. Another approach would be a group by:

```
select column_name, count(*) c from table_name
where column_name is not null
group by c
having c <> 1
```

If `column_name` of `table_name` is plausibly a primary key, the query above should produce no rows.

As for foreign keys, try this:

```
select column_name from table_name
except
select other_column from other_table
```

This should return an empty set if `other_column` of `other_table` has `column_name` of `table_name` as a foreign key.

As for automating the above tests over all the tables and each of their columns, I can't help there as my SQL vocabulary doesn't include Microsoft.

Note that passing the tests above is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a column to be a key. Determining which columns *should be* keys is as much a matter of intuition as algorithms, and if your starting point is taming a messy collection of raw data there may be columns that fail the tests but should nevertheless be keys.

Comment: @Estheralda, Neither of these queries can give the right answer because they only examine the data. The only right algorithm would be one that was based on database constraints or dependencies. Identifying PK and FK from constraints in SQL Server is easy enough: use the sys.key_constraints and sys.foreign_keys tables.